# How to deserialize Json to a simple Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have a json file like:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "Id1",
    "Value": "Value1"
  },
  {
    "Id": "Id2",
    "Value": "Value2"
  },
  {
    "Id": "Id3",
    "Value": "Value3"
  }
]
```

I need to move it to a simple Dictionary(string, string) and the id should be a key and value - value.

I can trim it and use `JsonDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);` but I think there should be more simple way.

Comment: Deserialize it into a list of an object with an Id and Value properties, and then use `.ToDictionary` to convert to the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with the following simple command:

```
var result = JArray.Parse(json).ToDictionary(token => token["Id"], token => token["Value"]);
```

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks for @Jamiec to pointing out my `result`'s type is `Dictionary<JToken, JToken>`.

```
Dictionary<string, string> result = JArray.Parse(json)
    .ToDictionary(token => (string)token["Id"], token => (string)token["Value"]);
```

Comment: `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray` is part of a external library

Comment: Just as the `JsonConvert` :D

Comment: It throws the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>'

Comment: @Kyocera It does work without any error. Here is a [dotnetfiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aBJtlV) for this.

Comment: @PeterCsala I think the point here is that youve made it a `Dictionary<JToken,JToken>` which cannot be used in place of `Dictionary<string,string>` even though you're right that outputting the JToken will yield the string. You just need some `ToString()` calls in your answer when you make the dictionary

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks, I've updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Yup the update works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

```cs
public class JsonItem
{
    public string Id;
    public string Value;
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonItem>>(json).ToDictionary(k => k.Id, v => v.Value);
```

You can check live demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/P8vONj